# MySQL update values of unique column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to:

1. select values from a unique column that match some condition, for example, numbers that can be divided by 2
2. alter those numbers
3. write the result back in the table. If altered numbers duplicate with numbers that are already there, skip this row insertion

Create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    number INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
    )
```

Populate:

```
INSERT test(number)
    VALUES
    (4), (5), (6), (9)
```

Do the trick:

```
UPDATE test
SET number = number - 1
WHERE MOD(number, 2) > 0
```

(this code fails with Duplicate entry '4' for key 'test.number')

I would like to end up with the following table:

```
id    number
1       4
3       6
4       8
```

I want number 5 with id 2 to be changed to 4 (number = number-1), and then to be rejected because it duplicates number 4 with id 1

I have tried the following also:

```
INSERT INTO test
 (id, number)
SELECT id, (number-1) AS number 
FROM test
WHERE MOD(number, 2) > 0
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id
```

But this fails with "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous"

Why do I want to do this? I have a table with a unique time series column, that is quite large. Values in that column are supposed to have one minute interval between them, for example:

```
19-Oct-2018 05:59:00
19-Oct-2018 06:00:00
19-Oct-2018 06:01:00
```

but some of them have non-zero seconds:

```
19-Oct-2018 05:59:00
19-Oct-2018 06:00:00
19-Oct-2018 06:00:20
19-Oct-2018 06:01:20
19-Oct-2018 06:02:20
19-Oct-2018 06:03:00
```

So I want to alter those by rounding up to the neighboring minute, but that leads to duplicates sometimes, and those duplicates should be discarded.

I have found some similar topics here, but was unable to figure out how to implement the answers to my case.

Comment: ___this code fails___ Fails with what, show us the error if you have one

Comment: this code fails with Duplicate entry '4' for key 'test.number'

Comment: `UPDATE IGNORE test
SET number = number - 1
WHERE MOD(number, 2) > 0;`

Comment: But if you start with `4,5,6,9`  the result will be `4,5,6,8`, not `4,6,8` as you think you want

Comment: After you do the update, you'll need to delete the rows that couldn't be updated to get the desired result.

Comment: And before you ask, no, there's no way to do the update and delete in one query.

Comment: Barmar, RiggsFolly, thanks a lot, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer, that was found in comments:

```
UPDATE IGNORE test
SET number = number-1
WHERE MOD(number, 2) > 0
```

request2:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE MOD(number, 2) > 0
```